# Incremental weakening Maxsat

Tags: smt, constraint-programming, sat, satisfiability, sat-solvers

I've an idea about MaxSat and have already implemented a naive Maxsat solver using MSU3 along with sequential encoding with minisat APIs

I was wondering if there's a way to speed up this solver.

I came with this paper:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264936663_Incremental_Cardinality_Constraints_for_MaxSAT

That talks about incremental weakening and it's implementation using totalizer encoding

Is there a way to implement incremental weakening with sequential encoding?

Will that give a considerable speed up?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin might be able to answer, he's an expert on the subject matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to implement incremental weakening with sequential encoding?

The *sequential counter* encoding can be built incrementally, that is, given a circuit `<= k(1..n)` this can be extended to `<= k+1(1..n)` and `<= k(1..n+1)`. When asserting a new soft-clause in OptiMathSAT, we incrementally extend the size of the *sequential counter* circuit by `1` in both directions (i.e. `k`, `n`). I see no reason why this couldn't be done along one dimension only.

After a quick glance at the results sections, it looks like the *iterative encoding* is significantly better than the *incremental weakening* technique. So you might as well try to implement the former approach rather than the latter.

The *iterative encoding* technique would require starting from `<= 0(1..n)` and progressively extend the sequential counter encoding along the `k` dimension. (As mentioned in the paper, some MaxSAT algorithms may want to increase the circuit in both directions).

- The inputs of the sequential counter circuit would be the negated literals of each soft-clause, so that the circuit counts the number of falsified soft-clauses.
- At the first iteration, `s_n_1` would be assumed to be `false`, back-propagating all inputs to `false`(i.e. forcing all soft-clauses to be `true`).
- If the first step is `unsat`, one extends `<= 0(1..n)` to encode `<= 1(1..n)`, and then assumes `s_n_1` to be `true` and `s_n_2` to be `false` at the next satisfiability check. During the search, as soon as one soft-clause is assigned to `false`, the remaining soft-clauses are back-propagated to `true` unless a new conflict is found.
- Repeat.

> Will that give a considerable speed up?

It's hard to predict performance without a rock-solid experiment. However, my suggestion is to go for it: it shouldn't be *that hard* to implement this approach and the results of the paper look solid.

The *sequential counter* encoding requires `O(n * k)` clauses, the same number as the *totalizer encoding* after applying the *k-simplification* at pag. 6, and `O(n * k)` auxiliary variables. Given the similar memory footprint, a similar performance gain is also possible.